# How do I check if the privacy setting when posting Facebook status is "Public" in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I've been looking anywhere about this and can't seem to improve my luck. In my fb app, the FB status I have posted is reflected in my blog site. I have already linked it, I just wanted to add feature by checking if it was set to "Public" then it should reflect in the blog site. I'm using PHP SDK. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to the fields list of a Facebook post : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

and here a link describing the privacy parameter : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

All the privacy informations are located in the "privacy" field wich is a JSON object.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am now trying to work the checking thanks to your links, I didn't know how to find those in the FB docs.

Comment: If you have any other problem feel free to ask. And if you can select my answer it'll be cool !